# Consequences of losing Hong kong landing slip

Tags: customs-and-immigration

I have lost my Hong Kong landing slip. What will happen when I exit Hong Kong? Can I get a visa for mainland China without the landing slip? Can the Hong Kong landing slip be replaced?

Comment: The one thing that's not answered in the other question is the question about a Chinese visa. You can't get one without the landing slip. I suggest exiting (eg to Macau) and coming back.

Comment: I exited Hong Kong twice last week. On both occasions, immigration did not collect the slip. I asked the immigration guy at the airport what to do with it and he told me  to "throw it away". I did have a separate China visa though.

Comment: Well , since I can not answer - I will leave it in comments - You do not need the slip. I am in and out of HK at least twice a month. They do not need the slip and in fact since they traded the stamp for slips they know that people do not keep them. it's always good to try and not loose it - but not really a problem,